# Autoselect printer according to print job with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, printing

I have a scenario where two different print jobs will happen. One is a sticker print, and the other a bill print. Is it possible to auto select different printers for the jobs respectively without the user requiring to select the printer every time he prints by using jQuery or any other method integration with PHP?